# JavaScript запрос к контроллеру ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать запрос к контроллеру на сервере, но сделать так, чтобы потом JS не ожидал ответа (я не имею ввиду синхронный и асинхронный режим).

Мне нужно отправить на сервер запрос с параметром, а сервер уже в зависимости от параметра должен перекинуть на нужную страницу.

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open('POST', '/Home/A', true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhttp.send("Text=123123");
```

Серверная часть

```
  public ActionResult A()
    {
        TempData["Text"] = Request["Text"];
        return View();
    }
```

А тут JS отправляет запрос на сервере я успешно считываю данные Request["Text"], но т.к. возвращаю `View()`, JS пытается его обработать.

Comment: Ну если 

    сервер уже в зависимости от параметра должен перекинуть на нужную        страницу

то возвращайте нужную вьюху или делайте редирект на нужный экшн

Comment: В том то и дело что если я возвращаю вьюху ничего не происходит

Comment: С ASP.NET не знаком, но должен быть return? На php ответ для Ajax делается через echo. 
Во-вторых: в коде возвращайте ссылку, а на JS делайте переход по ней. Т.е. примите ссылку и window.location...

Comment: Так не пойдет, т.к. в контроллере я устанавливаю  TempData["Text"] = Request["Text"]; а потом этот текст вывожу на страницу.

Comment: Можно как нибудь при переходе из JS (я использую window.location)  передать на другую страницу текст.

Comment: А может возвращать json и делать редирект яваскриптом?

Answer (score 1):

Может я не правильно понял, но ты можешь использовать `viewbag`, занести туда значение `false` и, перед следующей работой js, проверять `viewbag` с помощью `razor` на неравенство к `false`. Если будет равно, то не выполнять js.

Comment: Я использую ExtJs, и по моему это все из за него. 

Когда я посылаю запрос на сервер он принимает вызывает
return View();
но потом когда отлаживаю в браузере запрос перехватывает ExtJs и там ошибка.
Но я не понимаю какого он это делает)

Comment: Если я в JS использую  document.location то все норм отрабатывает, но если использую POST запрос JS, то он не переходит на нужный Action

Answer (score 1):

Почему просто не использовать `RedirectToAction` или `RedirectToRoute` при `return`?

Comment: public ActionResult ChangePassword()

        {

            TempData["Text"] = Request["Text"];

            return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Account");

        }

Это цикл друг мой=)

Comment: Как я понял из вопроса после какой-то проверки нужно показывать либо эту страницу, на которой какая-то часть должна быть обновлена, либо делать редирект на новую. Отсюда все что следует сделать - поставить проверку и если нужно перебрасывать на др. страницу использовать RedirectToAction, а если нужно обновить какую-то часть существующей страницы то использовать PartialView.

Comment: Страница "Д" с помощью JS отправляет пост запрос на сервер к контроллеру "А". Контроллер "А" должен вывести текст полученный от "Д" на странице "Ф"(это его вьюха)

Comment: То что вы написали в своем первом комментарии - получается у вас одна и та же вьюха. Но так как вы только что описали у вас две разные страницы - Д и Ф. Значит нужно использовать либо 

    return View("ViewName","ControllerName",requestText)

либо 

    return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName", new { text = requestText })

и никакого цикла не будет.